# compare grid row values with table row values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to compare grid view row values with the database values like for ex. for a particular id i have four records in table like..

```
id name
1   A
1   B
1   C
1   D
```

i m fetching these records in grid view and displaying.If the user deletes any gridview row and tries to update it, i want to compare grid row values with database values and find out which value user has deleted and save that value in any variable before updating in database for further operations.
How can i do this?Help Me

```
int j = 0;
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdAddress.Rows)
{

    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        drAdd = dtcomp.Rows[j];
        TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtAddress");
        if (!String.Equals(tb1.Text.Trim(), drAdd["Addr"].ToString().Trim(), StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            MAISTR.Add("Address:-" + tb1.Text.Trim());
            Newstr.Add("Address:-" + tb1.Text.Trim());
            oldstr.Add("Address:-" + drAdd["Addr"].ToString().Trim());
        }
    }
    j++;
}
```

I am using the above code but i am not able to get the changes if any row is deleted in grid.

Comment: On which event are you writing this code? Also what do you mean by "not able to get the changes"? Are you not able to get the values in "MAISTR", etc? Also what is the type of the variables "MAISTR", etc and where are they declared? Check this link as well if you can get your solution http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1619/how-to-perform-edit-update-and-delete-operation-in-gridview

Comment: i have written the above code before updating new data to database.the problem is while fetching data from databse i get for ex. four records and if user deletes a grid row from front end and then updates it.i just have to find out which row user has deleted and store that deleted row values for further use.

Comment: Did you check the link which I have given in the comment? In that link, the author handles the "OnRowDeleting" events to handle deleting of a row. This event gives you to row which is getting deleted. You can do your stuff with it there.